# MATLAB Most Frequent RGB value of an image

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB:
I have a map-like image that consists of several different colors. I need to know which color appears the most frequently.
Using `imread()` I have saved the image into a 3D matrix, and I need to find the most frequent pixel value (r, g, b).
I have tried `mode()` but it seems not working for 3D matrix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
im=imread (image);
Im1=im (:,:,1)*100+im (:,:,2)*10+im (:,:,3);
MostFrequent=mode (im1 (:));
MfR=MostFrequent/100;
MfG=(MostFrequent-MfR*100)/10;
```

I hope you get my point of converting 3d points to 1d and then back calculating the RGB values.

Comment: Thanks. I normalized the image first and followed your solution. It did work.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image into an index map using [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html), then you can find the most frequent index and get the corresponding color

```
rgbImg = imread('my_img.png');
[idx map] = rgb2ind( rgbImg, 1e-6, 'nodither'); %// consider changing tolerance here
m = mode( idx );
frequentRGB = map(m, : );
```

Comment: How to use the frequentRGB?

Comment: @TanSu have you tried the code? `frequentRGB` should be a three-vector with the most frequent RGB values.

Comment: I have used it, but the result is a bunch of 3-vectors.